# How to output false while using cl-json

Tags: json, lisp, common-lisp

In Common Lisp, I'm using [cl-json](http://common-lisp.net/project/cl-json/) to output json format, but how can I output a `false` instead of `null`?

Comment: As mentioned in the documentation, the encoder does not encode anything to false. This is the downside of a language that doesn't have different representations for null and false!

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young: still in many implementations you can declare for example a class slot to be of type boolean and query the class for the type of the slot... thus one could output the boolean NIL as false...

Comment: Any recommendations for Common Lisp? Thanks

Comment: The answer from jlahd is similar to what I did in cl-json. However, I moved my code to st-json, which encodes false as `:false`. The reason I moved, however, was that st-json uses strings as keys instead of keywords. The use of keywords is a problem when parsing unvalidated data because the keywords are interned and can never be GC'ed. This creates a big DoS attack vector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the set of utilities I use when I need to properly handle `false` with cl-json:

```
(defclass json-false ()
  ())

(defmethod json:encode-json ((object json-false) &optional stream)
  (princ "false" stream)
  nil)

(defvar *json-false* (make-instance 'json-false))

(defun json-bool (val)
  (if val t *json-false*))

(defun json-bool-handler (token)
  (or (string= token "true")
      (and (string= token "false") *json-false*)))

(defmacro preserving-json-boolean (opts &body body)
  (declare (ignore opts))
  `(let ((json:*boolean-handler* #'json-bool-handler))
     ,@body))
```

Now, to encode a literal `false`, I would way

```
* (json:encode-json-to-string `((foo . nil) (bar . t) (baz . ,*json-false*)))
"{\"foo\":null,\"bar\":true,\"baz\":false}"
```

Or, to encode a LISP boolean into a json boolean:

```
* (let ((something nil))
    (json:encode-json-to-string `((bool . ,(json-bool something)))))
"{\"bool\":false}"
```

Or, to read in JSON data preserving the distinction between `null` and `false`:

```
* (preserving-json-boolean ()
    (json:decode-json-from-string "{\"foo\":null,\"bar\":true,\"baz\":false}"))
((:FOO) (:BAR . T) (:BAZ . #<JSON-FALSE #x21029D2E4D>))
```

Of course, some care must be taken when reading in data like that;

```
* (when (cdr (assoc :baz *))
    'yep)
YEP
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, although I switched to st-json for built-in `false` support

Comment: You could also just `(defmethod json:encode-json ((_ (eql :false)) &optional stream)`